# Remove Item from ListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, vcl

Is there any way to remove item from listbox based on it's name but not index value? I would like to remove item named "Mouse" (which index # changes all the time).

Comment: Tom and Jerry looks like to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
listBox.Items.Delete(listbox.Items.IndexOf('Mouse'));
```